# OSX Terminal keeps on wiring over itself

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

So I found this issue happening and I don't quite know what to do about it.

I already tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11831296/os-x-terminal-text-stacking-on-top-of-itself). I also found that I can easily recreate this issue when I connect to another machine.

One way I found was when I was doing the Google CTF 2018 beginner's quest. If I connect, quit, and connect again my terminal looks like this:

[image]

Pretty standard. However when I try to search the man page for the text "CTF" by typing `/CTF` my terminal overwrites old output and it looks like this:

[image]
Not quite sure how to fix this.

**Here is my .bash_profile**

```
# Bash Prompt
PS1=" \[\e[1;32m\]ᚸ \[\e[0m\]"

# GZip with maximum compression
# usage: zipg <file>.tar.gz <dir>
alias zipg='env GZIP=-9 tar cvzf'
```

Any way to solve this issue?

Comment: Maybe I need another coffee but I can't work out either what you are showing us or where the problem is.  Are your screenshots showing a single terminal in each one, with content duplicated top and bottom?  Under the first screenshot you say "pretty standard", so I am guessing not (as that's not standard).  So are your 2 screenshots each showing 2 separate terminal windows which overlap, so we can't see the top of the bottom one terminal?  And whatever they are showing, where is the overwriting you refer to?

Comment: And the obvious question - if there is a problem I'm not seeing, a first guess would be it has something to do with your prompt. Does removing that make the problem go away?